# Anyone have Policy set up for SAS to be accessed only in HTTPS for storage access?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-policy

I would like to set up "Policy | Definitions" that whenver SAS token is created by users it has to have HTTPS enabled otherwise it Deny to create SAS token. how can I set this in Azure policy definition?

Comment: This is not supported. If the answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can define a custom policy for sas token. As per [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/tutorials/create-custom-policy-definition#azure-resource-graph), there is no alias for storage sas token.

And if the `Secure transfer required` is enabled in the storage account, even if you can create a sas token with `http` allowed, but eventually it will be rejected when accessing blob via `http`. So you may consider creating a [supportsHttpsTrafficOnly policy rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/tutorials/create-custom-policy-definition#policy-rule) as a workaround.